# Interactive function information for a given set of functions

Tags: front-end

By using

```
? "Global`* "
```

an interactive information appears with the corresponding expressions that match the given string pattern. It allows one to click on the function names to find a brief info for any of them.

I would like to display the same kind of interactive information, but for a given list of functions. If all the functions were called f1, f2 and f3, all what would be necessary is

```
? "f*"
```

But, for my problem, the functions have completely different names. How to do it?

Comment: You can use `Information[patt]` to do this, e.g., `Information[StringExpression["f*" | "g*"]]`

Comment: Thanks @CarlWoll. Your answer was very helpful. Now I understand that the expected output, for a given list of function names `{"f", "g", "h"}` , can be achieved by using `Information@StringExpression[Alternatives@@{"f", "g", "h"}]` . If you would like to answer the question, I will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Carl Woll's comment, here is a direct answer:

```
Information@StringExpression[Alternatives@@{"f", "g", "h"}]
```

Sometimes I find helpful to have a quick reminder of all the defined functions in a given package. The code below can be inserted by the end of the package to show such functions when the package is called.

```
definedFunctions = Select[
  Names["PackageContextNameHere`"<>"*"], 
  ToExpression[#, InputForm, DownValues] =!= {} &
];

Print[
  Information[
    StringExpression[
      Alternatives@@definedFunctions
    ]
  ]
];
```

Here is an example of the output:
[image]

Clicking on the names of the functions may provide additional helpful information (depending on how they were defined).